Movie about an oilman
I only watched a portion on T.V., a few days ago. I want to watch the whole movie, so I want to get this identified.

Color, but setting is probably early 20th century.
An oilman, whose name I cannot recall, devises an idea for what looks like an improvised oil extractor to me.
He goes on to build a lot of these, and eventually builds an oil empire.
One day, he and his business assistant (his young son), are asked by a man named Paul to dig oil near their ranch.
The oilman is hesitant, but eventually gives in.
He and his son then set out on a journey across dry lands to reach the ranch.

The description for the movie in the T.V. details said "a movie about business, politics and religion." Don't know if that's relevant.
Can anybody identify this movie?

what channel did you watch it on?  did you try looking through the channel's programming history?  also, was it in English?  was it live action?  etc.

Sounds like There Will Be Blood from 2007 with Daniel Day Lewis as a man building an oil empire.

A story of family, religion, hatred, oil and madness, focusing on a turn-of-the-century prospector in the early days of the business.

It follows the plot you mentioned, including the protagonist's oil exploits, his journeys with his son and his drilling for oil on Paul Sunday's family property. Won Oscars for actor and cinematography. Here's the trailer:



